# Composer and how to work with libraries

Tags: php, composer-php

So I am new to composer and I am trying to learn how it works. I have a question that I can't find the answer to anywhere on the internet.

Let's say I install the [lusitanian/oauth](https://packagist.org/packages/lusitanian/oauth) library by typing in the console `composer require lusitanian/oauth`. It will be downloaded in the vendor folder and all the 9 yards. Cool. But now, how can I start using it?

I am creating an `index.php` file and I include the autoload file with the following line:

`require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

Now when I go to the github page of the library, there is a [examples](https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib/tree/master/examples) folder. In my case I want to create a login with Facebook. The [facebook example file](https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib/blob/master/examples/facebook.php) requires a `bootstrap.php` file which is bugging me the most.

If I copy the content of the example file and paste it into my index.php file, the path to `bootstrap.php` is not correct. I thought of going through the vendor folder and finding the path so I can manually change it but first of all this seems ridiculous. I know that I should not be touching the vendor folder at all and secondly, fixing the path doesn't work. I start getting notices for missing undefined variable and a fatal error for calling a function that does not exist.

I checked other libraries and how to work with them. For example [monolog/monolog](https://packagist.org/packages/monolog/monolog) has a Basic Usage which is very simple and easy to understand. But how do I work with the `lusitanian/oauth` library in this case?

Comment: Did you look at the bootstrap file?  It tries to pull in an init.php with some basic config (which looks to be left to you).  I'm not familiar with the library, but just copy the bootstrap and init code example and adjust to your needs, and copy over the facebook example. These are examples.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Maybe this is how I should do it. I haven't looked at the bootstrap file but after looking at it it gave me ideas on how I could use it. Thank you. I was expecting some kind of common standard that every library uses but apparently every library is used in a different way.

Comment: Composer makes installing dependencies and setting up auto-loading easy.  Once you get an example working, perhaps you could edit your question to be more specific and add your workaround as an answer if you think that could be useful for others.

Comment: If you have an issue with usage instructions of package, at best contact the package maintainers. If you take a look at https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib, it seems that the maintainer is actually looking for help. Other than that, your question is too broad.